# I can't get this to work, php sanitize filters

Tags: php, validation, sanitize

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? I am trying to sanitize and validate a form user input with the php filters.  This input is going to go to a mySql database then an html page output so I need to remove all html tags and also provide security for mySQL.

Thanks.

```
      /*
 * BEGIN Sanitize and validate
 */

  // Adding fields to sanitize array.
$filters = array(
   'author'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,
   'title'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,
   'description'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS,
);


/*** apply the filters to the POST array ***/
$filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);


 // filtering out anything that isn't an email address
    $sanitized_email = filter_var(($_POST["email"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if ( filter_var($sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)  == TRUE) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Email Address.  Go Back.';
        exit;
    }

    /*
 * BEGIN sanitize and validate
 */
```

New code but still not working.  I am doing something wrong.  Still getting html in database and the errors are not working.

```
      /*
 * BEGIN Sanitize and validate
 */

  // Adding fields to sanitize array.
$filters = array(
   'author'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
   'title'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
   'description'  => FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,
);


/*** apply the filters to the POST array ***/
$filtered = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filters);
$filters = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string',$filters);
$filters = array_map('htmlspecialchars',$filters);
    if ( filter_var_array($filtered, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Input.  Go Back.';
        exit;
    }



// filtering out anything that isn't an email address
    $sanitized_email = filter_var(($_POST['email']), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    if ( filter_var($sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        echo '';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Email Address.  Go Back.';
        exit;
    }

    /*
 * BEGIN sanitize and validate
 */
```

2nd Edited below:

Got sanitized data to show in database by adding the sanitizing code to the area of the script that takes the data to the database.

```
 $_POST['author'] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['author']));
      $author=filter_var($_POST['author'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

      $_POST['email'] = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['email']));
      $email=filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

Now I have to finish trying to validate the email.

Comment: You didn't mention what the problem is. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0):

first thing: your query security is not provided by the filter module; that extension has nothing to do with database interaction, it only sanitizes or validates user input (and after that you can do a number of things with it without using a database)

**Update**: for example a quote or apostrophe that would break an sql query will still exist after using the filter module and that because the string is ok, it is your job to escape it if you decide to save it in the database (or it won't be a problem in a system like PDO where you bind parameters)

so, to secure your queries you should use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or if you are stuck with other systems you can use something that is appropriate (like escaping the input with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) for the mysql_* functions)

considering that you did not say what is the problem you are having I might add that if you want to "clean" user input and remove html also you should use the **FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING** flag instead of **FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS**

for me this script http://codepad.org/Wrgl0qEg works fine and removes the html tags from the input

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained better. For some reason I thought everyone can read my mind, LOL!  I tested the form, and got the correct error messages, and when successful it goes to the database, but in the database it still has the html codes.  I will go and try the above advice and let you know if it works.  Thank you so much.

Comment: an addition, even if it is not a problem in this script `filter_var($sanitized_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)` will return `$sanitized_email` if it is a valid email address and not true or false

Comment: @EmilyBonilla I don't think you have html tags in your database, I think you have html entities that show the initial tags.. it's a difference.. if you save a text with the B tag you won't see it as bold, you will see it wrapped between the opening and closing tags.. and that is because you are using `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` instead of `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING`, as I said in the answer also

Comment: This is what I have now and it is not working; meaning, I am still getting html in my database and the error messages are not working.  updating code above.

Comment: Ok, now I found out why the sanitizing wasn't working in the database.  I had to add the sanitized data to the script that took the data to the database.  Doh!  I will edit my original to show this for anyone else who needs it.  If it is wrong, please let me know...Thanks.

Comment: I finally got it all to work.  For the email validation, I had to use my original code minus the first line and use the Post email for the variable.  For some reason I can't use it with FALSE only with TRUE does the error message work.